# How to send "{" or "}" signs through send keys method in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sendkeys

I want to send { and } signs to the Active window in Visual Basic 2010.But the problem is when we send a key like "Backspace" we send it as "{BS}".So it also contains the { & } signs.
Therefore when we send { and } signs nothing happen.Anyone help me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}". **To specify brace characters, use
>   "{{}" and "{}}".** Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys,
>   but you must enclose them in braces. In other applications, brackets
>   do have a special meaning that might be significant when dynamic data
>   exchange (DDE) occurs.

Basically, you need to double up the braces to escape them, Like

```
{{}
```

to send a `{` opening brace, and

```
{}}
```

to send a closing brace. It may not be obvious at first glance, but that's just enclosing a brace character within braces. This is consistent with other escape sequences, such as using `\\` in C/C#/etc to indicate a literal `\` instead of a string formatting character.