# What does SendKeys "%{A}" mean?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sendkeys

I'm maintaining an old MS Access application, and I came across this use of SendKeys.

```
 SendKeys "%{A}"
```

I've seen SendKeys to create key presses for `"{ESC}"`, and various letters of the alphabet in the program. Is this `"%{A}"` doing some character conversion or hex number representation? Unfortunately, the behaviour in the application when it runs is not making the function clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to mean "Alt-A".

See [How to send "{" or "}" signs through send keys method in vb 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516137/how-to-send-or-signs-through-send-keys-method-in-vb-2010) for possible duplicate.

Also see [Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) for more information.