# How Do I Make a VB Script type "%" But Signalling That It's Not An Alt

Tags: vbscript

I have a block of code that basically opens opens notepad, makes a .bat file (batch) and I want it to type "%random%" but when I do that it comes out as "random" as the script thinks I'm doing Alt. Here's a small piece of the script.

```
wscript.sleep 75
shellobj.sendkeys "%"
wscript.sleep 75
shellobj.sendkeys "r"
```

(And so on until it spells out "%random%")

I know I can just do shellobj.send keys "%random%" but I'm making it look fancier by making it type it.
Please help as I've put so much time into my VBScript and I don't want it to fall apart because of this!

Comment: "I know I can just do shellobj.send keys "%random%""  --- I would suggest don't make it fancy...make it functional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send "{" or "}" signs through send keys method in vb 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516137/how-to-send-or-signs-through-send-keys-method-in-vb-2010) *(title makes no sense but the answer will answer your question)*